# What does 量能塞 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[Source from the news](https://tw.news.yahoo.com/%E9%87%8F%E8%83%BD%E5%A1%9E-%E7%A2%BA%E8%A8%BA%E8%97%8F%E9%BB%91%E6%95%B8-%E7%AC%AC2%E6%B3%A2%E6%AD%BB%E4%BA%A1%E6%BD%AE%E4%BE%86%E8%A5%B2-222108466.html)

> 量能塞…確診藏黑數「第2波死亡潮來襲」

Answer (score 2, accepted):

量能: capacity (of health care system)

塞: overwhelmed, overcrowded